# NSLayoutManager: Calling setLocation(_:forStartOfGlyphRange:) disables kerning in the whole string?

Tags: ios, swift, text, core-text, nslayoutmanager

I created simple [`NSLayoutManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/setLocation:forStartOfGlyphRange:) subclass that allows to set custom layout location for defined substrings:

```
class PositionableLayoutManager: NSLayoutManager {
    var xOffsetsPerGlyphRange = [(NSRange, CGPoint)]()

    override func invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange(charRange: NSRange, actualCharacterRange actualCharRange: NSRangePointer) {
        super.invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange(charRange, actualCharacterRange: actualCharRange)
        for (range, offset) in xOffsetsPerGlyphRange {
            setLocation(offset, forStartOfGlyphRange: range)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can define custom location of any character range like this:

```
let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRangeForCharacterRange(charRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
layoutManager.xOffsetsPerGlyphRange.append((glyphRange, customPointLocation))
layoutManager.invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: textStorage.length), actualCharacterRange: nil)
```

It works fine, the only problem is that any glyph range repositioned in this way is laid out and drawn without kerning. Here is an example:

[image]

In green box there is text drawn using my `PositionableLayoutManager` with without kerning, in pink box there is same text with kering drawn using `UILabel` for comparison.

How can I do the same thing but with proper kerning?

Comment: You are overriding the kerning values. I am not sure about how to do this, but try with a subclass to NSTypesetter. override the method setLocation(...) in typesetter and work there, may be this is helpfull